# Rounding Floating point Values

Tags: c#, c++, delphi, floating-point

I was on a task of porting C++ code to C#. There was a bug reported by client in my code. When I did debugging, here is what I got...

**C++ Code:**

```
double d = -0.0000000000018736038338473693;
String temp = String(SimpleRoundTo(d, -12))); // SimpleRoundTo() is from delphi
// temp is having -1E-12
```

**C# Code:**

```
double d = -0.0000000000018736038338473693;
string temp = (Math.Round(d, 12)).ToString();
// temp is having -2E-12
```

I did check the overloads by Math.Round(), not getting how to get the same result.

Comment: Double has a precision of 16 digits anyway, shouldn't you be using the [Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) type?

Comment: Isn't the C# result correct though? For example, I expect Math.Round(0.18, 1) == 0.2. Or do you want to round it down?

Comment: @llian Pinzon: Want to Round it down

Comment: If you want to round down then you have been using the wrong code all along. You should put the requirements in the question.

Comment: @Sayse What do you mean? The code in the question provides just the right number of digits usually necessary to identify an IEEE 754 double-precision number.

Comment: @PascalCuoq - I am suggesting since a large portion of the value will be lost, the OP may be better using decimal type for his numerical needs (I recognize he is "throwing" them away anyway)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer that the C++ version is giving is just plain wrong. That should be obvious. It's clear that `2E-12` is the correct answer since `SimpleRoundTo`, just like `Math.Round`, rounds to nearest.

So, if you wish to reproduce the erroneous output of the C++ version in C# you'll need to translate the Delphi RTL code to C#. That would involve working out exactly what `SimpleRoundTo` and the `String()` conversion does. Or p/invoke to a C++ DLL.

I would tackle this by trying to work out what the original code is **intended** to do. Express this in a mathematical way rather than in terms of the RTL functions. Once you have a clear specification of what you intend the code to do, code it in C# using the natural C# mechanisms. In other words, don't attempt a literal translation because one probably does not exist. Instead understand the intent of the original code and implement it from scratch in C#.

Looking at your code you perform rounding, and then convert to text. I would be looking for an approach that performed the rounding as part of the conversion to text.